Delete Realm object shown in UI without "invalid object" exception
I am showing a list of objects from my Realm database within my UI:
struct EntriesListView: View {
    @StateObject private var model = Model()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach($model.entries, id: \.self) { entry in
                    Text("\(entry.name)")
                }
            }
            Button("Add dummy entry") {
                Task {
                    await model.addDummyEntry()
                }
            }
            Button("Delete all") {
                Task {
                    await model.deleteAll()
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.model.load()
        }.onDisappear {
            self.model.unload()
        }
    }
}

Model:
@MainActor public class Model: ObservableObject {
    var realm: Realm?
    
    @Published var entries: [EntryRealmModel] = []
    var entriesToken: NotificationToken? = nil
    
    init() {
        do {
            realm = try Realm()
        } catch {
            realm = nil
        }
    }
    
    private func loadEntries() -> [EntryRealmModel] {
        guard let realm = realm else { return [] }
        let results = realm.objects(EntryRealmModel.self)
        return Array(results)
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard let realm = realm else { return }
        self.entries = self.loadEntries()
        
        entriesToken = realm.observe { (notification, realm) in
            self.entries = self.loadEntries()
        }
    }
    
    func unload() {
        entries = []
        entriesToken?.invalidate()
    }
    
    func addDummyEntry() async {
        guard let realm = realm else { return }
        
        let entry = EntryRealmModel(
            // ...
        )
        
        do {
            try await realm.asyncWrite {
                realm.add(entry)
            }
        } catch { }
    }
    
    func deleteAll() async {
        guard let realm = realm else { return }
        
        do {
            try await realm.asyncWrite {
                realm.delete(realm.objects(EntryRealmModel.self))
            }
        } catch { }
    }
}

The idea is taken from this question.
Adding works fine, entries immediately show up in the list.
But as when I delete all entries, the app crashes with:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'

Where could this error come from? I thought that the realm.observe takes care of loading the new contents after deleting.
BTW, you would think that the error comes from a faulty reference in Text("\(entry.name)"), but even with that commented out it crashes.

Realm/MongoDB has methods tailor made for SwiftUI. Use those. They work tightly with it to prevent these issues

Normally the async funcs are not inside the model since it's a class

As shown here return Array(results) I believe the issue is the Realm objects are being stored in a Swift Array. Deleting the Realm object will in fact delete it, but it will leave a nil value in the array and everything gets out of Sync. When working with Realm stick with Realm Syntax for the objects - it makes adding, editing and deleting seamless as the Realm Object, like an ObserveredResults or a List stays in sync with the underlying data and works very much like an array. You can see examples here

Also note that casting Realm results to an Array can also be a memory issue as then the objects are no longer lazily loaded.

The problematic code is this
private func loadEntries() -> [EntryRealmModel] {
   guard let realm = realm else { return [] }
   let results = realm.objects(EntryRealmModel.self)
   return Array(results) //<- causing the issue
}

Realm Results collections are memory friendly, lazy-loading and auto-updating. What that means is if a Realm object added, edited or deleted the Results object will always update to reflect the state of the underlying data.
If Realm SwiftUI syntax is used, it will, for example cause the view to refresh when that occurs.
But...
If those Realm objects are cast to a Swift Array... like this
return Array(results)

...all of that functionality goes out the window.
In this case, if an object is deleted from Realm, the corresponding element in the array will go to NIL, leading to a SwiftUI crash.
Even using ObservableObject does not work well with Realm objects - it's  Swift construct to be used to Swift objects
The other secondary issue is that Results objects are super memory-friendly because they are all lazily-loaded; meaning that thousands of objects have very little memory impact.
As soon as they are cast to an array though, all of that memory is gobbled up and a large dataset can overwhelm the device, causing weird, intermittent crashes. (it's also a lot slower)
The fix? Don't cast to a Swift array. Use the Results object as the datasource - there's a bunch of documentation on implementation here
Realm SwiftUI
Implement @ObservedRealmObject and @ObservedResults and it will work wonders for your app.

Change it to
ForEach(model.entries) { entry in


This won't help. If an Realm object is deleted from Realm t will leave a nil value in the array and will crash. Good thought though.

That should be ok, see realm.observe

What I was pointing out that model.entries is a SWIFT array, not a Realm Results or List object. @Published var entries: [EntryRealmModel] = []. When a Realm object is deleted from Realm, the array will not remove the entity at that index but will instead become NIL, which will cause the code to crash as it's a NIL entry in an array that doesn't support NIL entities.

Well thats pretty bad because this Realm API makes it look like its an object: realm.objects(EntryRealmModel.self)

Realm API is correct and safe: let results = realm.objects(EntryRealmModel.self) returns all EntryRealmModels as a Results collection; memory friendly, lazy-loading and auto-updating. The problematic code is the line following return Array(results) which casts all objects (which could be thousands) to a non-lazy loading, Swift array. With Results, if an object is deleted, the results object will reflect that and the UI would update. Swift, on the other hand will leave a nil element in the array, causing a crash.
